# Confluent Kafka poll, when does a message get committed

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python, librdkafka

I have a Python application that has autocommit=True and it is using `poll()` to get messages with a interval of 1 second. I was reading on the [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html#message-handling) and it mentions that polling reads message in a background thread and queues them so that the main thread can take them afterwards. I was a bit confused there on what happens if I have multiple messages `queued` and my consumer crashes. Would those messages queued from the background thread have been committed already and hence get lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the docs, every `auto.commit.interval.ms`, any polled offsets will get committed.

If you are concerned about missing data, you should always disable auto-commits, in any Kafka client, and handle commits on your own after you know you've actually processed those records.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to confirm about the fact anyways though.